# Assigning to DB to value greater than it can be stored, assembly

Tags: assembly, x86

I am making an assembler and i have to implement DB, DW and DD definitions. What happens if I try to do this in, for example x86 assembly:
`DB 0x12c`?
or
`DB 300 (decimal)`?
Will it split it into two bytes: `0xff` and `0x2d` (255,45)? Or?

Comment: Depends on the assembler, but many will at a minimum warn that a value is too big to fit. Some assemblers will warn and truncate. Others may just generate a hard error. It is your assembler, so you can choose to do it the way you want. I don't know of any assembler that will generate extra bytes to contain the overflow, but you could do it that way. It wouldn't be typical from my experience.

Comment: Thank you very much! it complicates it a lot if it creates extra bytes so i am asking whether any assembler does that. You made my life easier!

Comment: others may not support db, dw, etc in the first place as those are assembler specific...and then you dont have to worry about values larger than a byte or word...

Comment: what happened when you tried it?  with your assembler?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP could easily try this himself.

Comment: @DavidHoelzer, the first comment seems to indicate that the answer varies depending on the assembler, though.  So what might hold for one implementation might not hold for another.  That's something that would probably not be revealed in an experiment, but could be address in an answer.

Comment: I don't have where to try different assemblers, I wouldn't ask here if I had. My question was what common practice is. I am implementing this functionality right now so I will go with no support of overflow and hard error if it happens because it is easier for implementation.